# Template store path is invalid. Please make sure it exists or can be created: Unexpected path [path]

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I get this on my work machine (Win7 64bit), and this happens every time I open VS2010, and this is what I've done so far:
1. set folder properties (projects, project templates and item templates) from Import & export settings.
2. set projects, project templates and item templates paths from Options/Projects & Solutions.
3. found and manually set registry value that points to the above properties.

so every time I close VS 2010, nothing seems to save and I get the above error again and I find all values that I have set back to where it was.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I began getting this error after installing TFS Power Tools, and it looked to be related to that rather than to VS2010 itself.

I fixed it by going to `Tools->Options`, expanding `Team Foundation Server Power Tools`, clicking `Work Item Template`, and setting the default template store path to a path of my choice.

Once I saved that the message went away and I was able to start up my IDE unharassed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I apologize I have fixed this long time ago and I forgot about this submitted question! I even forgot how I fixed it... lol...

Comment: @nolimit - If this answer is correct, and I think it is because it solved the same issue for me, you should accept this answer so that Zind is credited for it.

Comment: done! yeah you're right it could be a solution that works for others.

Comment: Worked for me, in VS2013 as well.

Comment: What path did you use in replacement? the field was blank and I hit reset to set it to 'Work Item Templates', but it did not succeed, this is in VS2015