# Visual Studio 2015: Template store path is invalid error on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Every time I start Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, I get this following error message:

> Template store path in invalid.  Please make sure it exists or can be created: unexpected path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Work Item Templates

The path exists, and I create create / delete files in it.

I've tried

```
devenv.exe /safemode
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
devenv.exe /installvstemplates 
devenv.exe /resetsettings
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a3d84b8-0baf-45c5-a59d-bd46b22422a0/template-store-path-is-invalid-unexpected-path-cprogram-files-86microsoft-visual-studio?forum=vssetup

Aside from nuking VS from orbit, what I can do fix this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18901885/5041537 helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause.  The company's computer is configured to map my user profile to a network drive by drive letter, and the computer did not map the network drive to the correct drive letter on my machine.  Fixing the mapping fixed my problem.